# Lifting is my best known work

Tags: riddle, rhyme, science, chemistry

> Virtuous, but I'm of no form
>   My seat's right at the very top
>   Where gangs of many is the norm
>   My one peer is one that goes 'pop'
>
> Though my uses are many
>   Lifting is my best known work
>   At this my one peer beats me
>   Yet its temper, few dare irk
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's

> [helium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium)

Virtuous, but I'm of no form

> It's a [noble (virtuous) gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas) (Thanks @ChrisCudmore!)

My seat's right at the very top

> Top of the [periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#/media/File:18_column_periodic_table,_with_Lu_and_Lr_in_group_3.png)

Where gangs of many is the norm

> Gangs of many [elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_element)

My one peer is one that goes 'pop'

> [Hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen) is the only other in the [first period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_1_element) and it makes a 'squeaky pop' when lit

Though my uses are many

> Very useful - see [here](http://www.usesof.net/uses-of-helium.html) for some of the uses

Lifting is my best known work

> [Used in balloons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_balloon)

At this my one peer beats me

> Only [hydrogen is lighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_gas)

Yet its temper, few dare irk

> Hydrogen is [very flammable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen#Combustion) - ([Hindenburg disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindenburg_disaster))

Comment: Ach ninja'd....

Answer (score 12):

First time on the site. Just now created an account to answer this, hope I'm right. Please forgive formatting errors.

Answer:

> Helium

Explanation:

> Virtuous, but I'm of no form -> gas
> My seat's right at the very top -> right-top corner of the periodic table
> Where gangs of many is the norm -> Most elements in groups, but H and He alone
> My one peer is one that goes 'pop'-> ???
>
> Though my uses are many
> Lifting is my best known work -> Helium Baloons
> At this my one peer beats me - >H is lighter than He, would lift more 
> efficiently
> Yet its temper, few dare irk -> But it's flammable

Comment: (Welcome!) I just looked it up, and apparently it's *not* flammable

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That's a continuation of the prior explanatory sentence, talking about Hydrogen. "H is lighter than HE, and would lift more efficiently, but it's flammable"

Comment: Actually ignore me. I thought it was talking about helium

Comment: Thanks! The flammable part is referring to it's peer, which definitely is very flammable

Comment: The pop bit is a 'squeaky pop'. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are

> HELIUM.

The tags cued me to look at

> the periodic table, whose top two elements (you and your "peer") are hydrogen and helium. Hydrogen is the one that [goes 'pop'](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Hydrogen-burn-with-pop-sound), so the answer must be helium.

*Virtuous, but I'm of no form*

> A noble gas.

*My seat's right at the very top*

> Alone at the top of the periodic table.

*Where gangs of many is the norm*

> Most elements appear in rows of more than one in the periodic table.

*My one peer is one that goes 'pop'*

> Hydrogen - see above.

*Though my uses are many*
*Lifting is my best known work*

> Helium balloons.

*At this my one peer beats me*

> Hydrogen is lighter than helium?

*Yet its temper, few dare irk*

> Hydrogen is flammable and appears in nuclear fusion reactions.

Comment: beat you to it :P

Answer (score 5):

This is a fun answer, because *the title brought me here*, and I was determined to make it work no matter how much sense it doesn't make. If you'd like to play along, take a minute to think of *who*, not what.

---

**δῶς μοι πᾶ στῶ καὶ τὰν γᾶν κινάσω**

> [Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes)

Virtuous, but I'm of no form

> As far as I can tell he was an upstanding citizen but prescribed to no 'form' of religion.

My seat's right at the very top

> "Generally considered the greatest mathematician of antiquity and one of the greatest of all time."

Where gangs of many is the norm

> "[Greek mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_mathematics) constitutes a major period in the history of mathematics, fundamental in respect of geometry and the idea of formal proof. Greek mathematics also contributed importantly to ideas on number theory, mathematical analysis, applied mathematics, and, at times, approached close to integral calculus."

My one peer is one that goes 'pop'

> If Archimedes has but one peer, it would be Sir Isaac Newton, who invented the first practical reflecting telescope, with which Edwin Hubble discovered that the universe was expanding and we therefore now assume must have at some point went "pop".

Though my uses are many

> Founder of hydrostatics and statics, explained the principle of the lever, gave us Archimedes' principle, designed innovative machines such as his screw pump, compound pulleys, the odometer, and defensive war machines.  User of infinitesimals before modern integral calculus. Employed the method of exhaustion to approximate the value of π. [The list goes on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes).

Lifting is my best known work

> "Give me a place to stand on, and I will move the Earth." That's what it says in Greek up at the top. There's also of course, **"Archimedes' screw"**.

At this my one peer beats me

> "this" would be *The Calculus*, the invention of which is formally attributed to Newton.

Yet its temper, few dare irk

> "Archimedes died during the Siege of Syracuse when he was killed by a Roman soldier despite orders that he should not be harmed." - "General Marcellus was reportedly angered by the death of Archimedes."